# module.exports class is not found in editor and not a constructor at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to require a script:

```
const { Search } = require('../models/Search')
```

Which in return is giving me this error in the editor:

> Property 'Search' does not exist on type 'typeof Search'.

And when I execute the code, I get this error in the console:

> TypeError: Search is not a constructor

**models/Search.js**

```
module.exports = class Search extends Model { 
  constructor() {
    super()
    // Set some property values here
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module exports is `Search` class itself, not an object that contains it as `Search` property.

It should be either:

```
module.exports = class Search extends Model {...}
```

and

```
const Search = require('../models/Search')
```

Or:

```
exports.Search = class Search extends Model {...}
```

and

```
const { Search } = require('../models/Search')
```